# IBOutlet always nil in ViewController methods but ok in IBAction & Viewdidload

Tags: ios, null, swift2, iboutlet

I try to access some IBOutlet outside of Viewdidload and IBAction, and always get nil value. In Viewdidload and IBAction, those value are ok. Did i miss a part to declare or initialize something ?

The value are modified after viewdidload() because viewdidload is called bu the IBAction.

The View is created in storyboard, coming from a UINavigation Controller.

[connection table between ViewController and UIView:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcNF5.png)

The loginServer method is called by userCredential delegate, as below:

```
protocol userCredentialDelegate {
    func didUpdateCredential (sender:String, credential: Bool?)
}

class userCredential: NSObject {

var delegate:userCredentialDelegate?
// self.delegate = ViewController() removed

func loginServer (name: String, pwd: String) -> Bool {
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())
     {
     self.delegate?.didUpdateCredential ("login", credential: credentialStatus)
     }
}
```

Main controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, userCredentialDelegate  {

// set the shared instance
let user = userCredential.sharedInstance

@IBOutlet weak var incorrectCredentials: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var logButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func logButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print (incorrectCredentials?.hidden)
    if logButton.titleLabel!.text == "Log Out" {
        user.logoutServer ()
    } else {
        user.loginServer(username.text!, pwd: password.text!)
    }
}

func didUpdateCredential (sender: String, credential: Bool?) {
    switch sender {
    case "login":
        if credential! {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            incorrectCredentials?.hidden = false
        }
    default: break
    }
    if let credentialResponse = credential {
        loginStatus = credentialResponse
        }
    }

var loginStatus: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if loginStatus {
            incorrectCredentials?.hidden = true                    // always nil before, now ok
        } else {
            incorrectCredentials?.hidden = false                   // always nil before, now ok
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    user.delegate = self
    incorrectCredentials.hidden = true  // can work here
    user.getUserInfo ()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

[connection table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcNF5.png)

Comment: can you make a screenshot on you nib where you did connect the outlets to your controller? IBoutlets should be weak, so put weak before var.

Comment: tks. have updated code with weak and attached picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate to your user model in your viewDidLoad function.
Before doing `user.getUserInfo()` make `user.delegate = self`

currently you create a new Instance on the user model, that has nothing todo with you real loaded ViewController.

Comment: i have updated code: add user.delegate = self and remove self.delegate = Viewcontroller in user. Still see those nil value. i print in the console self.delegate from user and can see the correct data:  <App_Test.ViewController: 0x12fdb14d0>, so not sure what is still wrong. will investigate (i add a vote to your answer, but can not see, i just arrive in Stackoverflow).

Comment: i just removed user.getUserinfo () and can now can see those values correctly. user.getUserInfo is also messing up with that delegate. Thanks a lot Björn. Have been stuck on that for a day now.

Comment: oh great, maybe post your userGetInfo function and we can find the error

Comment: the issue related to userGetInfo was the same (i was resetting the delegate value). also (in above code) the segue was not working because of the main queue. all good now. Thank you Björn

Comment: Great, i wish you all the best :) And have fun on coding ;)